# Camera calibration and fish eye cameras

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all,
Can camera_calibration package be used to calibrate fish eye cameras?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135711/camera-calibration-and-fish-eye-cameras/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The quality of calibration will depend on the type of lens you´re using. For very high FOV lenses, camera calibration will likely fail or give unusable results, as the pinhole camera model that is used behind the scenes via OpenCV does not work with high FOV (> 180 deg, projecting points onto an image plane and all that). See also [this answer at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013513/fisheye-wide-angle-lens-calibration-in-opencv). For moderate fish-eye effect, calibration might work, though.

Your best bet is probably using [OCamCalib](https://sites.google.com/site/scarabotix/ocamcalib-toolbox) for determining proper calibration (see also comment in the link I posted above). After determining calibration parameters, you should be able to use your own variants of the world2cam and cam2world functions (If possible, you could even provide a ROS package with their implementation, so everybody can use them ;) ).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2014-03-05**:
Thank you. I dont have a fish eye lens with me at the moment. Will try it out when I get one. OCamCalLib looks promising

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: Probably yes. It should be easy to try, and should only take 15-30 minutes to try once you have a calibration target printed.

Long answer: You can probably use the camera calibration package to compute the appropriate camera intrinsics values for you camera. You may see a lot of cropping if you use the computed intrinsics with the stock image_proc to do rectification.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Perhaps too late, but I added this functionality (fisheye calibration and rectification with OpenCV>3) in this fork: [image_pipeline](https://github.com/DavidTorresOcana/image_pipeline)

You can calibrate (with a tool) and rectify fisheye cameras.

The results for high FOV (+180deg) are better that those achieved with the current implementation

---

Originally posted by [DavidTorresOcana](https://answers.ros.org/users/36987/davidtorresocana/) with karma: 31 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2